# MySQL function getting syntax error query does not return

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql function and store procedure.Here is my function of mysql with function name create_role that takes argument role_name.What I have to do is If there is any row with with particular role name then it should return 1 or true, if there is no role then it should return 0 or false.

```
CREATE FUNCTION create_role ( role_name VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE check_role INT;
    SET check_role = 0;
    SELECT * from role where role.role=role_name into check_role;
    RETURN check_role;
END
```

Comment: You have to use `delimiter //` at the beginning and `//` at the end of the function definition.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `IF` and `EXISTS`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION create_role ( role_name VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * from role where role.role=role_name) THEN
       RETURN 1;
    ELSE 
       RETURN 0;
    END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SET check_role = (SELECT count(*) > 0 from role where role = role_name);
```